# ActiveMQ broker hangs even if consumers are present

Tags: mule, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.9 with JDK 1.7 as recommended. I have integrated ActiveMQ with Mule. Periodically I am observing messages are getting stuck in queue even if consumers are present. If we re-start ActiveMQ those will get consume

I have configured like this in config. file:

```
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?transport.maximumConnections=30000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&amp;transport.keepAlive=true&amp;transport.useInactivityMonitor=false"/>
```

I went through lot of pages where similar issues had occurred, but didn't found solution

Any suggestions?

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.9 is quite old. For sure you want to use the latest rev 5.9.1, if not something much more recent.

Do you have a compelling reason to stay with 5.9?

Comment: I have to make compatible with Mule. BTW what is major difference in both?

Comment: Is it a JDK compatibility issue w/ Mule? Newer releases also support JDK 7 (with a lot of bug fixes). There were a few "stuck messages" bugs in 5.9 that have been fixed for _years_. You just need a newer version.

Comment: I tried downloading 5.9.1 its not available on apache site itself. Moreover this issue observed in later version as well like 5.10 or 5.11

Comment: If it happens with known stable version, than it sounds like you might be exhausting a connection pool or leaking some resources such as session, etc. Would need to see client-side Mule code to know more. I suggest writing up a simple JMS consumer to see if you are able to recreate the issue outside of Mule so you can rule out one or the other.